# Find out if there's equal elements in a list in a column in R

Tags: r

I have a column like:

```
> example
      [,1]     
Col.1 "a,b,c,d,e"
Col.2 "a,e,d"  
Col.3 "b,e,f,a"  
Col.4 "a,e"
```

Here, `a` and `e` is equal, because whenever `a` appears, `e` also appears. How can I find this? I tried using `duplicate()` but it only found "duplicate", not really "equal" elements.

```
> dput(example)
structure(c("a,b,c,d,e", "a,e,d", "b,e,f", "a,e"), .Dim = c(4L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(c("Col.1", "Col.2", "Col.3", "Col.4"), 
    NULL))
```

Expected output:

```
> output
[1] "a", "e"
[2] "b", "h" # if there are another equal elements
```

- edited for comment
  it is that both elements in a pair must always appear if one appears, in order to be counted as equal? But it doesn't necessary to be a pair (even it appears to be pairs in the example), I would prefer a general solution; for example, maybe a triplet...etc

Comment: that's a typo, sorry!

Comment: In the equivalency you defined ("whenever `a` appears, `e` also appears), it's only a one-way requirement.  Is it meant to be a two-way requirement?  For example, it is true that whenever `f` appears, `e` also appears.  Does that mean that `f` and `e` should be included in your list?  Or is it that both elements in a pair must always appear if one appears, in order to be counted as equal?  From the looks of your output, this "two-way" requirement is a necessary condition, but it's not stated as such in the problem statement.

Comment: it is that both elements in a pair must always appear if one appears, in order to be counted as equal? But it doesn't necessary to be a pair (even it appears to be pairs in the example), I would prefer a general solution; for example, maybe a triplet...etc

Comment: Maybe I am asking the same question as Andrew but Whenever `a` appears, `e` also appears but whenever `e` appears `a` doesn't appear. Is this an acceptable condition?

Comment: Really sorry folks, there's a typo; it should work vice versa!

Comment: @MathAvengers I updated my answer below in a way that I think meets all your criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function that, I think, deals with all of the specifications in the comments.  It should find any set of values that always show up together, whether pairs, triplets, etc...  To showcase this, I modified the data somewhat.

```
example <- tibble::tribble(
  ~x, 
  "a,d,e",
  "a,e,d", 
  "b,e,f,a,c", 
  "a,e", 
  "b,c,d,f"
)

find_equal <- function(data){
  all_vals <- strsplit(data, ",") %>% unlist %>% unique
  library(stringr)
  dums <- sapply(all_vals, function(x)str_detect(data, x))
  eq <- lapply(1:ncol(dums), function(i)apply(dums[,-i], 2, function(x)all(dums[,i] == x)))
  names(eq) <- all_vals
  out <- sapply(1:length(eq), function(i){
    if(any(eq[[i]]))paste(sort(c(names(eq)[i], names(eq[[i]])[which(eq[[i]])])), collapse=",")
    else{NULL}
  })
  out <- unlist(out)
  unique(out)
}

find_equal(example$x)
# [1] "a,e"   "b,c,f"
```